# Stop routing on click event in template in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

This is my angularjs app

```
var appblog = angular.module('Blogmain', ['ngRoute', 'ngSanitize']);
 appblog
.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
    debugger;
    //Setup routes to load partial templates from server. TemplateUrl is the location for the server view (Razor .cshtml view)
    $routeProvider
        .when('/Blog/Index', { templateUrl: '/BlogTemplate/BlogList.html', controller: 'ListBlog' })
        .when('/Details/:ID', { templateUrl: '/BlogTemplate/BLogDetails.html', controller: 'DetailsBLog' })
        .when('/blogcategory/:ID', { templateUrl: '/BlogTemplate/blogcategoryList.html', controller: 'BlogCategory' })
      .otherwise({ templateUrl: '/BlogTemplate/BlogList.html', controller: 'ListBlog' });

}])
```

everything is work fine rough is working fine but the problem is  in blogcategoryList.html page, i have a javascript function where user show list type view or grid type view but the problem is when the function is fire 
automatically the ng-route is fire and

```
otherwise({ templateUrl: '/BlogTemplate/BlogList.html', controller: 'ListBlog' })
```

is fired and BlogTemplate/BlogList.html page is render 
i want to stay in /BlogTemplate/blogcategoryList.html page

this is my javascript function

```
<script>
function showhide(id) {
    debugger;
    if (document.getElementById) {
        var divid = document.getElementById(id);
        var divs = document.getElementsByClassName("tt");
        for (var i = 0; i < divs.length; i = i + 1) {
            $(divs[i]).fadeOut("slow");
        }
        $(divid).fadeIn("slow");
        if (id = "listshow") {

            $("#list > a").addClass("list-grid Active");
            $("#grid > a").removeClass("Active");
        }
        else {
            $("#grid > a").addClass("list-grid Active");
            $("#list > a").removeClass("Active");
        }
    }
    return false;
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    // document.getElementById("listshow").fadeIn("slow");
    $("#listshow").fadeIn("slow");
});
```

Comment: Can you show your javaScript function?

Comment: function showhide(id) {   
        if (document.getElementById) {
            var divid = document.getElementById(id);
            var divs = document.getElementsByClassName("tt");
            for (var i = 0; i < divs.length; i = i + 1) {
                $(divs[i]).fadeOut("slow"); }
            $(divid).fadeIn("slow"); if (id = "listshow") {
              $("#list > a").addClass("list-grid Active");$("#grida").removeClass("Active"); }
            else { $("#grid > a").addClass("list-grid Active"); $("#list > a").removeClass("Active"); }} return false; }